# htaccess - redirect subdomain to another URL and mask it

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I would like all requests to 
"forum.maximumtrainer.com" to be redirect to 
"http://maximumtrainer.com:4567/"
Where my actual forum is hosted.

I have tried a lot of htaccess code but without success.
I can do a normal redirect fine, but I would like the URL to always stay "forum.maximumtrainer.com/..." instead of changing to "maximumtrainer.com:4567/.."

Here is my current htaccess file (first Rule is for the forum)

```
RewriteEngine on

#Just do a normal redirect, not hiding the new URL
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^forum.maximumtrainer.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://maximumtrainer.com:4567%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To mask it you would need to use DNS. Using something like `Fowarding with Masking` on. You would need to check your settings on your registrar to do Fowarding with masking. However that typically won't show the `URI`

Or if you want to forward requests to a backend or another server you need to use `mod_proxy` and `mod_proxy_http` which can be enabled in the apache config.

```
ProxyPass / http://maximumtrainer.com:4567
ProxyPassReverse / http://maximumtrainer.com:4567
```

Using mod_rewrite

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^forum.maximumtrainer.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://maximumtrainer.com:4567%{REQUEST_URI} [P,NC]
ProxyPassReverse / http://maximumtrainer.com:4567
```

**NOTE: You can not use ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse in .htaccess. It needs to be in the Apache config or vhost file.**

In .htaccess only using the `[P]` flag

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^forum.maximumtrainer.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://maximumtrainer.com:4567%{REQUEST_URI} [P,NC]
```

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/proxy.html

Comment: Thanks i'll look to use mod_proxy. I thought it was doable with .htaccess only but seems not. 
Not sure if one of theses option is better? https://docs.nodebb.org/en/latest/configuring/proxies.html
what would you suggest? thanks a lot.

Comment: Almost there. I configured nodeBB url to "forum.maximumtrainer.com"
Only minor problem is that is still show the port number in URL: http://forum.maximumtrainer.com:4567/